# How do I only get TOP-level child tags that match what I am looking for?

Tags: jquery, xml

For example, if I have:

```
<conversations>
  <status>1</status>
  <conversation>
    <status>0</status>
    <text>Hi</text>
  </conversation>
</conversations>
```

How do I go about getting < status > for < conversations > while ignoring < conversation >?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [child selector, >](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$('conversations > status')
```